# Unable to create project in android due to java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: android

I am trying to create new android project, but I am gettting an error like 
**java.lang.nullexception error. 
So no subcomponents are appearing under src and other folder.**

Please let me know what I need to install to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you went to android sdk manager and downloaded the sdk's you need?

Eclipse -> window -> android sdk manager.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll find everything you need in the official guide, [Installing SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html). Especially check if you have added the necessary platforms.